# Combine two Emacs buffers?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Given two separate emacs buffers, how can I combine them by joining the first rows of each, then the second, etc? I'll probably need to add a space after each line in buffer #1 so I don't end up with "a b1 2", for example.

Buffer #1

```
a b
a c
c x
```

Buffer #2

```
1 2
5 4
3 2
```

Result

```
a b 1 2
a c 5 4
c x 3 2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to use [rectangles](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Rectangles.html) to do this. Just copy the contents of buffer 2, and then rectangle-yank (C-x r y) them into buffer 1, with the point one space to the right of 'b' in the first line.

Answer (score 5):

Use `M-x 2C-associate` and `M-x 2C-merge`. You might want to use `C-h v 2C-windows-width` or `M-x 2C-shrink-window-horizontal.`

Comment: There's always something new to discover :)

Comment: Although the trivial example in the question is more easily dealt with using rectangles, `2C-merge` has the considerable advantage of not requiring you to manually deal with long lines, which probably makes it the more robust answer. It also works exactly as you'd hope with buffer narrowing, which is great.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use the '[paste](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/)' tool for such applications (no Emacs though..).  If you are using Linux it should be available by default.

It's as simple as:

```
$ paste file1 file2 > file3
```

which will merge the two files 'file1' and 'file2' into the output 'file3' the way you asked for.  By default TABs are used as column separators, but this can be changed via the '-d' option.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing the combining outside of emacs, you could save the two files, and combine them using awk.

Look at this example: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/awk-question-331224/#post1682282